# Generate PDF files with audio/video attachments with php

Tags: php, tcpdf, mpdf

Is there a way to attach audio/video files to PDF files using php? The only option I could find was itext which is written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You pretend play audio or video inside PDF? or you want to insert a external link?

For external link, I use https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf

Installation:
$ composer require mpdf/mpdf

Example:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');

$mpdf->WriteHTML('<a href="http://hcmaslov.d-real.sci-nnov.ru/public/mp3/Queen/Queen%20\'Another%20One%20Bites%20The%20Dust\'.mp3">Play the song</a>');

$mpdf->Output();
```

[Screenshot: PDF generated with mpdf library with external link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLWkl.png)

[Screenshot: Playing the song after clic on the external link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2xMI.png)

Comment: It would be great if I could have an embedded player for mp3/video files. It's enough to add links to files that can open it on external applications